# OnMouseUp not responding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the very simple line of code for an object in Unity:

```
void onMouseUp()
{
     Debug.Log("Click");
}
```

The object is not responding to the onMouseUp function. I have tried moving the code from the parent to the object, giving both a rigidbody and giving the parent a collider. Changing OnMouseUp to OnMouseDown didn't do anything either.

I also checked if there was something wrong with my pc not wanting to read the code by putting the *Debug.Log* part of the code in *void start*, which gave me a message in my debug log (as expected).

[The object with its parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Hyr.png)

Am I misunderstanding something and missing a part of the code?

Comment: Did you try [`OnMouseUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) with an **upper case** `O`?

Comment: Wow I'm really not that bright am I? This solved it :/

Comment: spelling mistakes .. we all went through those so don't worry ;)